# Discord.py multiple missing arguments

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a simple command that requires to arguments to be passed; datatype and length, I have

```py
@ran.error
async def ran_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError):
```

This just gives an output if there is a general error, I'm looking for something where if no arguments are provided then do `a` or if only one is provided then do `b`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#variable) you can easily pass all arguments like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def ran(ctx, *args):
    # do something
```

To check if arguments are provided you could first get the number of all arguments and and check if it is 0, than your error handling comes into play:

```
@bot.command()
async def ran(ctx, *args):
    # get number of arguments provided
    number_of_arguments = len(args)
    if number_of_arguments == 0:
        # error handling
    else:
        # perform command action
```

Have a look at my linked website for more information.